# Routing changes when upgrading to Angular 16

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular16

I am using a lazy-loader to generate components in my Angular project. These are then displayed using a component-injector when they're ready. This worked fine in Angular 15 and lower.

Now that I am upgrading to Angular 16 the routing link has been changed where the path on the page isn't just the value in the path field it is now enclosed in brackets and contains other parent values.

An example link in Angular 15 would look like `localhost:8080/aaa/ccc` now in Angular 16 it looks like `localhost:8080/aaa/(bbb//menu:ccc)`

The bug is specified further in this question: [routerLink change in Angular 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76170863/routerlink-change-in-angular-16)

Although, the solutions listed will not fit in my circumstance because I am using component-injection I cannot just edit the `routerLink` in a link.
The other answer specifies that I need to avoid using relative links altogether.

Why would an Angular update break this major feature of Angular?
Is there a solution where I can continue using lazy-loaded components with relative links for Angular 16 and beyond?